# How to debug binwalk tool?

Tags: debugging, debuggers

My lecturers have requested that I debug `binwalk` in order to understand how it works and develop new features so that it can extract more. I tried to use `gdb` to debug `binwalk` but it results in the error message "/usr/bin/binwalk": not in executable format: File format not recognized". What other tool can be used to debug it?

Answer (score 3):

> I tried to use `gdb` to debug `binwalk` but it results in the error message "/usr/bin/binwalk": not in executable format: File format not recognized".

In order for `gdb` to interface with a binary executable, the binary must have one of the following [object file formats](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/Internals%20Object-File-Formats):

- a.out
- COFF
- ECOFF
- XCOFF
- PE
- ELF
- SOM

The binary must also have intact section information, as `gdb` relies on `libbfd`. Since `binwalk` is written in Python and interpreted by the Python interpreter instead of being compiled in to an executable binary that conforms to one of the aforementioned formats, `gdb` cannot be used to dynamically analyze `binwalk`.

> My lecturers have requested that I debug binwalk in order to understand how it works and develop new features so that it can extract more.

If your primary goal is extending the functionality of `binwalk`, then dynamically analyzing it may not be as productive as looking at

- the [the source code](https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk)

as well as [documentation](https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk/wiki) on

- [The signature file format](https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk/wiki/Signature-File-Format)
- [Creating custom signatures](https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk/wiki/Creating-Custom-Signatures)
- [Creating custom plugins](https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk/wiki/Creating-Custom-Plugins)
- [Scripting with the API](https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk/blob/master/API.md)

But if "debugging" `binwalk` is the primary focus, then [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) or using a Python IDE will work.

Answer (score 2):

Binwalk is written on Python language. Please try pdb. Python debugger.

Comment: or any modern python IDE with debugging capabilities such as PyCharm.